# Show that the iterations $x_{n+1}=x_n+y-f(x_n)$ converge to a solution of $f(x)=y$ for every $x_0,y\in \Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ satisfy $$\forall x_1,x_2\in \Bbb{R}^n, |(f(x_1)-f(x_2))-(x_1-x_2)|\le {1\over 2} |x_1-x_2|$$
Show that the iterations $x_{n+1}=x_n+y-f(x_n)$ converge to a solution of $f(x)=y$ for every $x_0,y\in \Bbb{R}^n$. **Hint:** show $f$ is continuous.

I noted that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le {3\over 2} |x-y|$, meaning $f$ is $3\over 2$-Lipschitz, meaning $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Now, $|(f(x_n)-f(x_{n+1}))-(x_n-x_{n+1})|=|y-f(x_{n+1})|\le {1\over 2}|x_n-x_{n+1}|={1\over 2}|y-f(x_n)|$, meaning $|f(x_{n+1})-y|\le{1\over 2}|f(x_n)-y|\le({1\over 2})^2|f(x_{n-1})-y|\le...\le({1\over 2})^{n+1}|y-f(x_0)|$. Noting $f(x_n)=z_n$, a sequence in $\Bbb{R}^n$,it is clear that $|z_n-y|\to 0$. But it only ended up in showing a sequence that is a composition, converges, but what about $x_n$? How can it be possible to show that $f(x_n)$ converges without showing $x_n$ converges first? I am a little confused and could use your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unusual that we first obtain $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=y$ before knowing whether $(x_n)_n$ converges.

Suppose $(x_n)_n$ doesn't converge. Then for some $r>0$ there exist arbitrarily large $n,n'$ with $n<n'$ and  $|x_n-x_{n'}|>r.$  But $(f(x_m))_m$ converges, so for $n$  large enough we have $$|f(x_n)-f(x_{n'})|<r/4<|x_n-x_{n'}|/4.$$ But from the initial  condition on $f$ this gives $$(1/2)\cdot |x_n-x_{n'}|\geq |(x_n-x_{n'})-(\;f(x_n)-f(x_{n'})|\geq$$ $$\geq |x_n-x_{n'}|-|f(x_n)-f(x_{n'})|>(3/4)\cdot |x_n-x_{n'}|>0,$$ giving $$(1/2)\cdot |x_n-x_{n'}|>(3/4)\cdot |x_n-x_{n'}|>0,$$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\phi(x) = x+y-f(x)$ is a contraction, with
$\|\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2)\| \le {1 \over 2} \|x_1-x_2\|$, hence it has a unique fixed point.

If we let $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$, then it is straightforward to show that the sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy and hence $x_n \to x$ for some $x$. Then $\phi(x) = x$ shows that $f(x) = y$.